# Resetting a Visual Studio C++ project's settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I changed some parameters in a Visual Studio C++ project, and now I don't remember how to "go back". Is it possible to reset the build settings?

I don't mean the IDE settings (menu *Tools* -> *Import and Export Settings*).

Comment: Found any solution? I am in the same problem now (7 years later)...

Comment: I found the answer in page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx I will write about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command "**devenv /resetsettings**" will restore Visual Studio back to its original factory state.

You can find list of devenv switches [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

> Am I the only person that can read?!

The only way I know how to reset a "Parameter in a Project's Settings",,,

**Is to open the Project file(csproj, vcxproj) with a text editor, and remove the block defining that parameter.**

If you wanted to reset the Allow Isolation value, you would delete this text.

```
<AllowIsolation>true</AllowIsolation>
```

When project files are loaded by visual Studio, values which are not explicitly defined in the file, are assumed to be using the default. This will only work if the property has a default value(can't change some).

NOTE: This is NOT the same as Deleting the value from the Project Properties Dialog in VS. That method writes a blank value to your project file.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get the previous/saved version of your Visual Studio project (*.vcproj) from your software version control system.

Comment: Hmm, no. I don't mean resetting this project's settings. I mean the default settings VS uses when creating a new project. Since I changed them in one project, it seems to use this new ones in all new projects.

Answer (score 1):

## Here is the awful method I used in Visual Studio 2022.

1. In "Property" pages, expand the individual configuration you want.
2. Click "All Options" and find the **bold** options you had changed.
3. To restore the defaults, click the options and select "<inherit from parent or project defaults>".
4. Click "Apply", then it will recover its original value.

Otherwise, you can compare the *.vcxproj with the project templates.

Answer (score 0):

As many wrote here before, there is a need to reset your visual studio to default settings. Just follow this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.90).aspx